# Symfony2 - Container issue with ajax

Tags: ajax, symfony, controller, containers

I've been stuck with a peculiar issue I can't find a solution for.

In usual flow, my **WelcomeController/listAction** calls two services from the container, with the method $this->container->get("the_service"). **Service1** and **Service2** are found and used correctly.

I need to make an ajax call to a controller **WelcomeController/changeListAction** who, in turn, forwards to my WelcomeController. In this situation, the service **Service1** is found but when **Service2** is called I've got an error 500.

I tried to retrieve **parameters** too this way ($this->container->getParameter("my_param")), and while it works without ajax, it also failed with it. The **container** seems to be the problem, but the **Service1** is found no matter what !

Do you have any ideas ?

Thank you !

Services definitions in services.yml :

```
google_user_helper:
    class: Company\MainBundle\Helpers\GoogleUserHelper
    arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager, @bit_google.api, @session, %demo_length%]        

utils:        
    class: Company\MainBundle\Helpers\Utils    
    arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager,%indemnities%,@google_user_helper]
```

The always working **Service1** is the google_user_helper.

Comment: Can you show us the code which generates the error so as the full error you are getting? (Exception name with message). My first thought is that your AJAX is hitting the **prod** environment.

Comment: If you call services from controller you don't have to use container - you can call them directly through $this:

    $this->get('<service_name>')